# How we can add UIPopOverController on UIButton?

Tags: iphone, uibutton, uipopovercontroller

I have a problem  since last half-an-hour.I am using `UIButton`  and I want to show `UIPopovercontroller` on it.But It crashes on it's `touchUpinside action`.I know this can we easily done if i use `UIBarButton` but I have some `UI specification` that's why I can't use `UIBarButton` and `UIToolbar`.

So please if someone have any idea about showing `UIPopovercontroller` on `UIButton` then please help me.Help would be appriciated.

Comment: why don't you post your code & crash report here.

Answer (score 5):

```
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:button.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the below Code :

```
-(IBAction)Show_Menu_Controller:(id)sender
{
    if (_colorPicker == nil) {
        self.colorPicker = [[[ColorPickerController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain] autorelease];  
        _colorPicker.delegate = self;
        self.colorPickerPopover = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:_colorPicker] autorelease];               
    }
   [self.colorPickerPopover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(600.0f, 250.0f)];


    [self.colorPickerPopover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(365,-118 , 300, 200) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];  **//Set the Origin & Direction of PopOverController accordingly**

}
```